# rxjs, Как реализовать: родитель слушает состояние checked дочерних элементов

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2, observer

## Как я это вижу:

Родитель `ParentComponent` и множество дочерних элементов `ChildComponent` взаимодействуют через `IsAnyChildСheckedService`

`ParentComponent` подписан на массив стримов и слушает, изменилось ли у какого-нибудь `ChildComponent` cостояние на true, если хоть один true, но `ParentComponent` получает уведомление true

---

Пробовал просто создавать в родителе инстанс EventEmitter и передавать его каждому дочернему элементу, но если дочерние элементы запускают сообщение одновременно, то нарушается очередность [(обсуждение, код и возможный хак здесь)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566930/eventemitter-simultaneous-events-blend-how-to-prevent-this/39575703#39575703)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно реализовать через Observable
**IsAnyChildСheckedService**:

```
setArr(arr) {
    this.arr = arr;
}
getState(arr) {
    var self = this;

    return new Observable(observer => {
        setInterval(() => {
                if(self.isChangeArr(arr)) {  //Проверка массива
                  observer.next(true);
              }
            }, 5000);

    });
}
```

**ParentComponent**:

```
...
listener() {
   this.isAnyChildСheckedService.subscibe(res => {

        // res = true
   })

}
```

а в ChildComponent через сервис IsAnyChildСheckedService передавать массив